# make-series in kusto step 1 year

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

In Azure data explorer we have multi options of the timespan to use, which they are "day, minute, second ... etc).

for example:
we have a dataset which we want to step on it each year not a day or month.
in Kusto there is no option to step in year like `1y`
instead of that i found the only option that we set 365d like the following example

```
data
| make-series count() default=1.0 on timestamp from start_time to end_time step 365d
```

but the result are like the following:

```
"timestamp": [
    "2016-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z",
    "2017-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z",
    "2018-01-02T00:00:00.0000000Z",
    "2019-01-03T00:00:00.0000000Z"
],
```

expected results:
is there any way to set the results starting on the first of Jan each year like the following example:

```
"timestamp": [
    "2016-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z",
    "2017-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z",
    "2018-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z",
    "2019-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z"
],
```

Answer (score 3):

Time-series work on regular time windows - and year (month, or quarter) - are not regular.

You can still use 'summarize' aggregation to create non-regular series:

```
data
| summarize count() by startofyear(timestamp)
```

If you need to complete the "defaults" later - you can do it with join:

```
let _default = 0;
let _start =  datetime(2019-08-03 07:40:21);
let _end = now();
let data = datatable(timestamp:datetime)[datetime(2020-08-03 07:40:53), datetime(2020-08-02 07:40:53)];
    data
    | summarize Count=count() by timestamp=startofyear(timestamp)
    | join kind=rightouter (
        range s from _start to _end step 1d 
        | summarize by timestamp = startofyear(s)
    ) on timestamp
    | project timestamp=coalesce(timestamp, timestamp1), Count = coalesce(Count, _default)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you create an intervals set for use in the make-series range

```
let Intervals = toscalar(data 
| where timestamp between(start_time..end_time) 
| summarize array_sort_asc(make_set(startofyear(timestamp))));
```

then simply index into the intervals array to get the group value

```
| extend IntervalGroup = array_index_of(Intervals, startofyear(timestamp))
```

and use that in the make-series

```
| make-series count() default=1 on IntervalGroup from 0 to array_length(Intervals) step 1
```

The same query would work for months as well, just swap out `startofyear` for `startofmonth`. It gives you an accurate yearly (or monthly) division of the time period.

Answer (score 0):

To create an actual series with default values for non-existent timespans:

```
// Show only values for e.g. this and last year
let _default = 0;
let _start =  startofyear(datetime_add("year", -1, now()));
let _end = startofyear(now());

data
| extend Year=startofyear(timestamp) // can be any non-continuous timespan aggregation (e.g. MonthYear / Quarter / etc.)
| summarize Count=count() by Year
| join kind=rightouter (
    range s from _start to _end step 1d 
    | summarize by Year = startofyear(s)
) on Year
| project Year=coalesce(Year, Year1), Count = coalesce(Count, _default)
| extend DummyGroup=1 // to summarize all values together into the DummyGroup 1
| summarize YearSeries=make_list(Year), CountSeries=make_list(Count) by DummyGroup
| project-away DummyGroup
// Now you can use series regression analysis functions, etc.
| extend series_fit_line(CountSeries)
```

(Credits to Alexander Sloutskys for his approach above, which I took as a basis to then transform into an actual series)